# Question regarding the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Let's say I want to find the limit of $n^\frac{1}{1+n}$ as n tends to $\infty$. The answer my books states is 1, so I try to work my way back to the definition through the answer:
I need to prove that $|n^\frac{1}{1+n} -1|\lt \epsilon $ for $\epsilon \gt 0$ and $n\ge N, N \in \mathbb N$. 
Let $n^\frac{1}{1+n} -1 = h $
$n = (1+h)^{1+n}$

Using the binomial expansion gives $n \gt \frac{n(n+1)h^2}{2}$ and simplifying gives $h \lt \sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}}$
Now as we need to prove that $h \lt \epsilon$, we choose $\epsilon$ such that $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}} \lt \epsilon$. Simplifying that would give us the minimum $N$ possible. 
Now lets do the same thing assuming that the limit is $2$. Then,
$n = (2+h)^{1+n}$. Again using the binomial expansion, $n \gt \frac{2^nn(n+1)h^2}{2}$ or $h \lt \sqrt{\frac{2^{1-n}}{n+1}}$. Choose $\epsilon$ such that $\sqrt{\frac{2^{1-n}}{n+1}} \lt \epsilon$
Simplifying this stuff gives another $N$.
Doesn't this mean that $2$ can also be a limit? And likewise every other real number, as we could have any $N$ corresponding to the $\epsilon$ I choose? What's wrong with my understanding?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure it's meant to be 1? Pretty sure this limit is just infinity; if you're sure the book says that, I honestly think it might be written wrong.

Comment: If you meant $n^{\frac{1}{n+1}}$ you should change that. As your post is written, it looks like you are trying to prove something that is not true.

Comment: @John Douma Sorry about the typo, that's precisely what I meant.

Comment: @Robbie Acknowledged.

Answer (score 1):

You're saying:

1. We write $n = (1+h)^{n+1}$.
2. This necessitates $h<\sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}}$.
3. Giving you the benefit of the doubt, *if* we choose $n$ such that $\sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}} < \epsilon$ (we never choose $\epsilon$ – we must take general $\epsilon>0$), then this shows that $h<\epsilon$.
4. Follow similar steps for $n=(a+h)^{n+1}$.

OK... so we've shown that we can't write $n = a^n$ for $a>1$ as $n$ gets large. I think you'll probably agree this is not what you set out to prove! It certainly doesn't show convergence of the sequence in the question.

What you should be trying to show instead is that $(1+h)^{n+1} \geq n$ for sutiably large $n$ (and for any $h$).

**Addition**

Does your confusion come from the following? To show the convergence we want, for any $h$, to find $N$ such that for $n>N$
$$
n^\frac{1}{n+1} - 1 < h
$$
We then add 1 to both sides to find the condition above. Note that adding $a+1$ to both sides gives
$$
n^\frac{1}{n+1} + a < h + 1 + a
$$
which is not useful.

Answer (score 1):

You ***don't*** choose $\epsilon$. That's *given*: for every $\epsilon$ you need to find $N$ such that, whenever $n>N$ you have $|h|<\epsilon$.

Your work is good. Since $n>1$, also $n^{1/(1+n)}>1$, so you know that
$$
h=n^{1/(1+n)}-1>0
$$
which simplifies things. Since $n=(1+h)^{n+1}$ you can indeed state that
$$
n>\frac{n(n+1)h^2}{2}
$$
and therefore
$$
h<\sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}}
$$
Now take $N$ such that
$$
\sqrt{\frac{2}{N+1}}<\epsilon
$$
For $n>N$ you have $n+1>N+1$ and so
$$
\frac{2}{n+1}<\frac{2}{N+1}
$$
and you're done: when $n>N$ you have
$$
h<\sqrt{\frac{2}{n+1}}<\sqrt{\frac{2}{N+1}}<\epsilon
$$
But can we find $N$? Yes: the condition becomes
$$
N+1>\frac{2}{\epsilon^2}
$$
and such $N$ certainly exists.

Comment: All that you've done assuming the limit to be 1, can't it be done assuming the limit to be 2, or 3 , or anything else,? Surely we would end up with a lower limit to $N$?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind No. After I prove that the limit is $1$, I know that the limit cannot be different. You can prove this in general, which is easier than doing the proof for the particular case.

Answer (score 1):

$n\ge 1\implies n^{1/(n+1)}\ge 1$ so it is true that for every $n\ge 1$ there exists $h_n\ge 0$ such that $n^{1/(n+1)}=1+h_n,$ and you deduce correctly that $n^{1/(n+1)}\to 1$.

If you assume that $n\ge 1\implies n^{1/(n+1)}\ge 2$ then you can say that for every $n\ge 1$ there exists $h^*_n\ge 0$ such that $n^{1/(n+1)}=2+h^*_n$ and conclude that $n^{1/(n+1)}\to 2.$

But $n\ge 1\implies n^{1/(n+1)}\ge 2$ is $false$.

And if  $n^{1/(n+1)}=2+h^*_n$ with $h^*_n<0$ then the inequalities you wish to obtain by the Binomial Theorem are not valid because the binomial expansion will contain negative and positive terms

Comment: Thanks for answering. What I wanted to ask is, given that I correct my expressions(involving the Binomial Theorem) if I assume $h_n^* \lt 0$, won't I obtain another value of $N$ that will satisfy the definition of the limit?

Comment: @AmbicaGovind . No. That won't work. A convergent sequence has ONE limit.